# Convexity or concavity of a minimum function

Tags: convex-analysis

I'm currently trying to prove convexity or concavity of

$$f(x,y) = \min (x,y)$$

but I'm not quite sure which it is. Visually, it looks convex but for two points on the same straight line it seems like neither. Does this mean the function is neither concave nor convex in general? And convex/concave on specific parts of its domain?